# stemming. i need to write a code for this

Tags: python-3.x

If you search for something in Google and use a word like "running", Google is smart enough to match "run" or "runs" as well. That's because search engines do what's called stemming before matching words.

In English, stemming involves removing common endings from words to produce a base word. It's hard to come up with a complete set of rules that work for all words, but this simplified set does a pretty good job:

If the word starts with a capital letter, output it without changes.
If the word ends in 's', 'ed', or 'ing' remove those letters, but if the resulting stemmed word is only 1 or 2 letters long (e.g. chopping the ing from sing), use the original word.
Your program should read one word of input and print out the corresponding stemmed word. For example:

```
Enter the word: states
state
```

Another example interaction with your program is:

```
Enter the word: rowed
row
```

Remember that capitalised words should not be stemmed:

```
Enter the word: James
James
```

and nor should words that become too short after stemming:

```
Enter the word: sing
sing
```

Here is the code:

```
word = input("Enter the word:") 
x = 'ing' 
y = 'ed' 
z = 's' 
first = word[:1] 
last = word[-1:] 
uppercase = first.upper 
if word == uppercase: 
 print("")

elif (x in word) == True: 
 word = (word.replace('ing',''))
 print(word)

elif (y in word) == True: 
 word = (word.replace('ed',''))
 print(word)

elif (z in word) == True: 
 word = (word.replace('s',''))
 print(word)
```

Comment: do i have the right idea with this




word = input("Enter the word:") 
x = 'ing' 
y = 'ed' 
z = 's' 
first = word[:1] 
last = word[-1:] 
uppercase = first.upper 
if word == uppercase: 
print("")

elif (x in word) == True: 
word = (word.replace('ing','')) print(word)

elif (y in word) == True: 
word = (word.replace('ed','')) print(word)

elif (z in word) == True: 
word = (word.replace('s','')) print(word)

Comment: Try putting your code in the question and follow the formatting guidelines so your code shows up properly. 4 spaces at the beginning of each line for blocks of code.

Comment: Have you looked at existing libraries? This is not an easy problem. Perhaps [NTLK](http://nltk.org/) would be helpful?

Comment: Check out [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/)

Answer (score 1):

I see two options. Either this is a homework question, in which case - please try to solve your own homework.

The other case - you need this in real life. If so, please look at NLTK for Python natural language processing needs. In particular see http://nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html

Answer (score 0):

Install NLTK toolkit 
and try this

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
PorterStemmer.stem_word(word)
```